# MYSQL Procedure to transfer data from one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm new in mysql and plsql as well. I was trying to write one procedure to transfer data from one table to another but couldnt reach to end.

I have one table Mall_Sales (Consist of three different malls like Delhi_Mall, Mumbai_Mall, Chennai_Mall and these malls falls in column **Mall** with their period of transaction in column name **Period**)

Mall_Sales

```
Mall              Period
Delhi_Mall        2015-09-01
Delhi_Mall        2015-09-02
Delhi_Mall        2015-09-03
Mumbai_Mall       2015-09-01
Mumbai_Mall       2015-09-02
Chennai_Mall      2015-09-01
Chennai_Mall      2015-09-02
```

And

```
Latest_Period_Mall
Mall              Period
Delhi_Mall        2015-09-03
Mumbai_Mall       2015-09-02
Chennai_Mall      2015-09-02
```

I'm trying to write a procedure whenever period of mall updates in Mall_Sales, Store MAX period of all malls in Latest_Period_Mall table.

And whenever new MAX date comes from Mall_Sales table should replace the existing records in Latest_Period_Mall table.

I have tried this

```
Create or replace Procedure Update_Data
AS
    INSERT into Latest_Period_Mall table(Mall, Period)
        Select Mall, MAX(Period) Period 
        from Mall_Sales
        group by Mall
Go
```

Please correct me with your inputs and the every time updation part in Latest_Period_Mall table rather than adding records.

Best

Comment: Why are you storing the latest period in a table when you can readily get it from a query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I need this procedure to work with a talend etl tool. So that I could use this information for the period last record received and pull missing data from that date to till date.

Comment: You can use a query or a view for the tool.

Answer (score 0):

A view essentially saves the query:

```
create view Latest_Period_Mall as 

    Select Mall, MAX(Period) Period 
    from Mall_Sales
    group by Mall
```

So that you can simply query the view like a regular table.

```
    select * from latest_period_mall
```